# getting multiple data from msacess ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

when ever i run this code i get only one output i would like to get all results starting with letter `D`

```
 using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
 {
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE title LIKE 'D%' ",conn);
  conn.Open(); 
  OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd); 
  adapter.Fill(results); 

  if (results.Rows.Count !=0) 
    {                
      using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())                        
      {
       while (reader.Read())
        {
          title = reader[1].ToString();
          searchbox.InnerText = title;
        }
      }
    }
     else
         {
            searchbox.InnerText = "NOTHING FOUND";
         }
```

**defualt.aspx**

```
<li id="searchbox"></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your reader is going through the results and changing the title with each row. you need to "add" the value of each row to the result: `title += reader[1].ToString();` this won't look correct at first, you'll have to adjust it, but it should get all the results out.

Comment: add a space and a semicolon to each output with `title += reader[1].ToString() + "; ";` or you could add a new line, etc.

Comment: i actually did this `searchbox.InnerText += title;`
and it worked thanks :)

Comment: even better, save a step. tip: if you need to build up a fancy string as the results come out, use StringBuilder. (using System.Text;).